# Linter - Parsing error: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript

O professor passou alguns exercicios, um deles era usar o Git e executar um linter para verificar vários arquivos de código. Aqui ele me deu nesse código mas sinceramente nao consegui entender e nem identificar.

```
    // Você nao pode modificar as linhas de 2 à 5:
    const lib = {
    abc: 123,
    def: 234,
    };

    object =abc {
      def: lib.def,
      abc: lib.abc,
      xyz: 567,
    };

    console.log('O valor de abc est' + object.abc);
```

Comment: `object = abc` era para ser um objeto com propriedades `def`, `abc` e `xyz`?

Comment: Acredito que sim. Agora nao entendi o motivo do erro de Parsing selecionando token {

Comment: mas repare que se `object = abc` era para ser um object qual o nome da variável `object` ou `abc`? mude para `const object` e chame o `object.abc` já deverá funcionar

Comment: Obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro é de sintaxe, mais especificamente nessa parte:

```
object =abc {
  def: lib.def,
  abc: lib.abc,
  xyz: 567,
};
```

o correto seria:

```
object = {
  def: lib.def,
  abc: lib.abc,
  xyz: 567,
};
```

Pois você está atribuindo um objeto à variável `object`, e o "abc" não tem sentindo onde estava.

Comment: pode ter sentido se colocar o `abc` entre aspas, assim chama o `object["abc"]`

Comment: @PedroPinto, é uma das interpretações possíveis

Comment: const lib = {
           abc: 123,
          def: 234,
         };

         const object  {
           def: lib.def,
          abc: lib.abc,
          xyz: 567,
        };

        console.log('O valor de abc est' + object);

e agora o erro no linter muda para: 
 Unexpected string concatenation  prefer-template (para a ultima linha)

Comment: @MarceloMedeirosdosSantos Essa vírgula no final depois do 567 também não ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

O linter recomenda utilizar uma novidade : ES2015 (ES6) nomeada "Littéraux de gabarits" (em frances) ou "template literals".
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

É entao possivel formatar uma linha de texto escrevendo diretamente o nome da variavel 'inline'.

Para resolver o problema, deve-se trocar

```
    console.log('O valor de abc est' + object);`
```

por

```
    console.log(`O valor de abc est ${object}`);
```

Comment: Oi Marcelo! Esta tua resposta não é a resposta ao problema. O problema era como outros indicaram a sintaxe errada na declaração do objeto. _Template literals_ é útil, mas se não corrigires a sintaxe `object =abc {` vai dar o mesmo erro na mesma. Acho que a resposta do Samir merece ser marcada como aceite/correta.

Comment: Oi @Sergio .. é que depois de usar o que nosso amigo Samir escreveu surgiu um outro erro para  Unexpected string concatenation prefer-template (para a ultima linha) e a resposta foi esta que eu passei. Desculpe por postar no local errado ;)

Comment: O código sem erros ficou assim:

        // Vous ne pouvez pas modifier les lignes 2 à 5:
        const lib = {
        abc: 123,
        def: 234,
        };

        const object = {
        def: lib.def,
        abc: lib.abc,
        xyz: 567,
        };

        const str = `La valeur de abc est ${object}`;

       console.log(str);